# How to fix BLE device auto disconnection in Android O+?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I was connecting the BLE device with my android application for many days, But when I upgrade my android application to API level 28 it starts auto disconnecting after 12 hours on Android O+ mobile devices.

I have tried by changing clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE) with
clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE) but by using it BLE device stops even connecting.

I am unable to share my whole code because it is out of my company policy.

```
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    stopDemoReadings();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress) && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    //Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}
```

I am getting following error inside BluetoothGATT onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=8 at the time of disconnection.

Comment: post your code where you are building connection with ble device

Comment: @Quicklearner have edited my question please check.

Comment: where are you calling this method  ?  using background service ?

Comment: yes using service

Comment: Do you require anything else to understand the problem

Comment: Try set autoConnect parameter to true, so it will reconnect automatically if it drops for some reason. Also make sure you have a Foreground service so the app isn't killed.

Comment: @Emil I am trying this solution

Comment: @hannnapatait check the service if its running or not in every device

Comment: probably service is getting destroyed , add logs and check the behaviour

Comment: service is running it is in forground

Comment: is it working 24x7 ?

Comment: yes it is running 24x7

Comment: I have noticed in my log file that i am getting following status  'onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=8'